(Non)existence of unsatisfiable 3-CNF involving partitioned variables
Suppose we have Boolean variables $a_1, ..., a_r, b_1, ..., b_s, c_1, ..., c_t$. Consider 3-CNFs that look like $$\bigwedge (\_a_i \vee \_b_j \vee \_c_k)$$ where $1 \leq i \leq r$, $\_a_i$ means $a_i$ or $\neg a_i$, and so on. Additionally, any triple of indices $(i,j,k)$ can appear at most once in the whole formula: for example, if one of the clauses is $a_1 \vee b_1 \vee \neg c_1$, then you can't also have $\neg a_1 \vee b_1 \vee c_1$, but you can also have $a_1 \vee \neg b_1 \vee c_2$.
A simple observation: the maximum number of clauses that can be in any 3-CNF of this kind is $rst$, which is much smaller than the number of possible assignments for the variables (that may or may not satisfy), which is $2^{r+s+t}$.
My question is, do there exist values for $r,s,t$ such that there is a 3-CNF of this kind that is unsatisfiable? The only intuition I have is that if we don't have 'enough variables', e.g. if we only have $a_1,b_1,c_1,c_2$, then it seems that there are so few clauses that it's easy to find an assignment that satisfies them all. But I don't have a great idea of what happens if we introduce more variables.
Edit
After running some computations, I can confirm that there are indeed unsatisfiable examples. The smallest cases are for $r=3,\ s=2,\ t=2$, e.g. if we use the following clauses:
(¬a_1, b_1, c_1)
(a_1, b_1, c_2)
(a_1, b_2, c_1)
(¬a_1, b_2, c_2)
(¬a_2, ¬b_1, ¬c_1)
(¬a_2, b_1, ¬c_2)
(a_2, b_2, ¬c_1)
(a_2, ¬b_2, ¬c_2)
(a_3, ¬b_1, c_1)
(¬a_3, ¬b_1, ¬c_2)
(a_3, ¬b_2, ¬c_1)
(¬a_3, ¬b_2, c_2)

This of course means that there are unsatisfiable 3-CNFs whenever we have at least this many variables.
Now, some follow-up questions that I am now interested in: given such an unsatisfiable ('unsat') 3-CNF, can we deduce

any necessary conditions about the number of times each variable must appear, or
whether an unsat 3-CNF in more variables must contain clauses that are also found in an unsat 3-CNF in a subset of those variables?

